# Insert data of two columns in a graph legend - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(product = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 count = c(3, 4, 6, 7),
                 name = c("ball", "pen", "notebook", "pencil"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = count, fill = product)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

Is it possible to make the legend with information of two columns? I mean, I would like to make it like: a - ball; b - pen; c - notebook; d - pencil.

[image]

I know I can merge the columns using stringr::str_c and make a new legend like this, but I would like to use a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is combine the columns in one line using `paste0` and assign these labels in `scale_fill_discrete` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(product = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 count = c(3, 4, 6, 7),
                 name = c("ball", "pen", "notebook", "pencil"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = count, fill = product)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = with(df, paste0(product, " - ", name)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>